# How to make voxels inside a cube translucent in VTK?

Tags: python, vtk

I have a vtk Volume that I have rendered using VTK.

What I want to have is a cube such that if the cube is placed inside the volume, the voxels inside that cube would appear to be less opaque than those outside the cube. Is that possible?

Comment: have you tried using SetOpacity(value) method on the inner cube actor? For example, something like cubeActor.GetProperty().SetOpacity(0.5)

Comment: No, I wish to set the opacity for the voxels inside the cube, not the opacity for the cube itself. For example, if the whole volume had an opacity of say 0.5, then a cube with an opacity 1.0 that contains a part of those voxels would not change the opacity of the voxels. I want to have only the voxels within the cube to have an opacity 1.0.